# How can I make treasure ships appear?

Tags: super-mario-bros-3

What are the requirements to make the white "treasure" ships (which lead to airship levels full of coins) appear in *Super Mario Bros 3*?  Can I make them appear intentionally?

Comment: good god I had no idea any of this was possible! curse you SE:Gaming! NOW I HAVE TO TRY!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To make a Hammer Bros. turn into a coin ship:

1. Ensure there's a Hammer Bros. left on the world map
2. Start a level and finish with:

   1. A multiple of 11 coins (11, 22, 33, etc.)
   2. A score ending in 10 (2010, 3410, etc.)

Each second left on the clock gives you 50 points.  That means you should end with an even number of seconds left on the clock if you have a score ending in 10.  If you have a score ending in 60 you should finish with an odd number of seconds on the clock.  Anything else and you're out of luck!

There are also white mushroom houses that appear [if you get every coin on a particular level](http://gametipcenter.com/super-mario-brothers-3-white-mushroom-house-and-white-treasure-ship-secrets) in each of the first 7 worlds:

```
1–4: 44 coins
2-2: 30 coins
3–8: 41 coins
4–2: 22 coins
5–5: 28 coins
6–7: 78 coins
7–2: 41 coins
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you mean turning a wandering Hammer Bro into a white treasure ship. From [Gamespot:](http://www.gamespot.com/nes/action/supermariobros3/cheats.html)

> Morph a wandering hammer brother into a treasure ship.
>   To turn a wandering hammer brother (the ones that walk about on the world map) into a white ship full of coins, collect a number of coins that is a multiple of 11. Make the tens digit in your score match the multiple of 11. Stop the timer at the end of the stage that you are playing in on an even number.One combination would be: 11 coins, 9,310 as your score, and the timer at 104. This only works in worlds 1, 3, 5, and 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can have any multiple of 11, so 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, and 88. Then you need to make sure your score has a tens digit of the same number as your coin multiple. Example: if you have 11 coins your score will need to look like this 01000[1]0. As long at the second to the last digit (the tens digit/ the digit I put in brackets) is the same as your coin multiple you will get the treasure ship. It will only work on world 1, 3, 5 and 6. There must be a hammer bro on the map and you must stop the timer on an even number by hitting the goal block when the timer changes to an even number.

Comment: Your answer does not add anything that the other two answers from ~4 years ago state. Duplicate answers are frowned upon here and may be subject to deletion.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are only half true.

It works on worlds 1, 3, 5, and 6. There must be a live Hammer Brother to be turned into the ship.

You can get the treasure ship by ending a level with a number of coins that are multiple of 11 (11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88). Then you have to match the tens digits of your score to ONE of the following rules:

a) the tens digits is equal to your coin digits (i.e: you have 33 coins, the tens digits is 3): finish the level with an even number of seconds, or

b) the tens digits is equal to your coins digits + 5 (i.e: you have 66 coins, the tens digits is 6 + 5 = 11, then it is 1): finish the level with an odd number of seconds.

The second rule here (b) is often omitted in these answers, but it works.